# JTS "points must form a closed linestring"

Tags: polygon, area, jts-topology-suite

I'm trying to create a polygon and calculate it's area using

```
    final GeometryFactory gf = new GeometryFactory();

    final ArrayList<Coordinate> points = new ArrayList<Coordinate>();
    points.add(new Coordinate(0,0));
    points.add(new Coordinate(0,1));
    points.add(new Coordinate(1,0));
    points.add(new Coordinate(1,1));
    points.add(new Coordinate(0,0));


    final Polygon polygon = gf.createPolygon(new LinearRing(new CoordinateArraySequence(points
        .toArray(new Coordinate[points.size()])), gf), null);

    System.out.println(polygon.getArea());
```

And I get the error:

```
 points must form a closed linestring
```

When I tried to use the points :

```
points.add(new Coordinate(0,0));
points.add(new Coordinate(0,1));
points.add(new Coordinate(1,0));
points.add(new Coordinate(1,1));
points.add(new Coordinate(0,0));
```

I've received area = 0 .

I'd like to know what I've got to do in order to calculate the area correctly without getting any errors.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

In the conversion world, what you've built is known as a "bowtie".

[image: As-built]

If you really want that shape, you need to conform to topology rules by making a multipart polygon with "left hand rule" part vertices {0,0},{0.5,0.5},{0,1},{0,0} and {0.5,0.5},{1,0},{1,1},{0.5,0.5} (reverse the order [or just swap vertices 2 & 3 in each part] to generate "right hand rule" polygons).
[image]

If you wanted a rectangle, then you need to order the vertices so that no line segment crosses another (in the direction appropriate to your software):

```
//Left hand rule 
points.add(new Coordinate(0,0));
points.add(new Coordinate(1,0));
points.add(new Coordinate(1,1));
points.add(new Coordinate(0,1));
points.add(new Coordinate(0,0));

//Right Hand Rule
points.add(new Coordinate(0,0));
points.add(new Coordinate(0,1));
points.add(new Coordinate(1,1));
points.add(new Coordinate(1,0));
points.add(new Coordinate(0,0));
```

[image: LHR Rectangle]

Comment: Right, and because the question is about jts, it does not care about the ring orientation and for jts `POLYGON ((0 0,0 1,1 1,1 0,0 0))` is just as valid as `POLYGON ((0 0,1 0,1 1,0 1,0 0))`. But do not draw butterflies or hour glasses.

Comment: Thanks for the great answer and the detailed explanation !